# post create test for user count failing. Should be changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, rspec, controller

Been trying to figure this out for a while now, but can't seem to go green. Here is the rspec error that I am getting:

```
 1) UsersController POST create with valid parameters creates a new user
     Failure/Error: expect {post :create, user}.to change(User, :count).by 1
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controllers_spec.rb:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top     
(required)>'
```

Here is my relevant test in the users_controllers_spec:

```
describe UsersController do
  let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create :user}

  context 'POST create' do 

   context 'with valid parameters' do 
    before {post :create, user}
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.build :user}


    it 'creates a new user' do 
     expect {post :create, user}.to change(User, :count).by 1
    end


   it {should respond_with 200}
 end
```

And here is my users_controller create method:

```
def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
     sign_in @user
     flash[:success] = "Welcome #{@user.name.capitalize}! Please complete your profile."
     redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
   else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Also, here is my factories.rb file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do 
    name  "John"
    email "John@example.com"
    password  "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
  end
end
```

What am I missing? I feel like it is something really obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any `User` validations that would prevent the creation of multiple users with the same name, email, etc?

Comment: Yes. I have a uniqueness validation for email.

Answer (score 0):

Your test involves creating a second user with `FactoryGirl`, but the creation of the second user is failing because the email is the same as the first and you have a uniqueness validation on that attribute.

You can either not create the first user at all or you'll need to make the emails different (e.g. by passing in an email parameter to your `FactoryGirl` call or changing the Factory to make each email address unique).